# do_shortcode not considering price filters with woocommerce native products shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, shortcode

I have some filters like this inside my plugin

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'custom_variable_price', 99, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'custom_variable_price', 99, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_sale_price', 'custom_variable_price', 99, 3 );
... and so on
function custom_variable_price( $price, $variation, $product ) {
    
    if((!is_admin() && !wp_doing_ajax()) && (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product() || is_front_page())) {

        return get_discounted_price($product, $price);

    }

    return $price;

}
```

This works and changes my prices dynamically everywhere, even with woocommerce native products shortcode (through page editor) EXCEPT when calling it inside do_shortcode in functions. And cannot figure out why.

Here is the example where these filters do not work

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_cart', 'offer_additional_products_cart');
function offer_additional_products_cart() {
    
    if(is_cart()) {
        
        echo '
        <div class="company_home_title">'.__('Do not miss', 'company_translations').'</div>
        ';
        
        echo do_shortcode('[products limit="4" orderby="popularity" class="quick-sale" on_sale="true"]');
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely normal because you are using `do_shortcode()` **in cart page** and your custom price **is not allowed in cart page** *(see your restrictions in your `IF` statement)*.

To allow your custom product price in cart page, you should add `is_cart()` in your `IF` statement, then `do_shortcode()` will work as expected, displaying the right custom product prices.

But you should better use only `! is_admin()` in the `IF` statement inside your functions like:

```php
function custom_price( $price, $product ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $price = get_discounted_price($product, $price);
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Because with your current code, the prices don't get changed in cart and checkout pages...